# Shower arm and flange looks terrible

Tags: shower, flange

The hole for the shower arm and flange was put in too close to the tile. The flange sits on top of the tile and looks terrible. What can I do to improve this?

Comment: A picture would help to understand your concerns.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a picture that shows the situation from the tub side. Also include a picture of the back side of the wall, as you may need to have access there, as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could bring up the level of the wall to the match the tiles.  A few ideas on how to do that

- install another row of tiles
- install a few tiles artistically near the arm pipe.  Like a triangle of 1-2-3 tiles
- get a piece of Corian to level with the tile.  Can dress the top edge with a simple bullnose

Comment: I disagree with @Chenmunka. This is an ideas question, not a specific how-to.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that by flange you mean escutcheon.

Bend the flange to match the profile of the wall and tiles.

Trim the flange so that it lays flat.

Add something behind the flange to bring it parallel with the tiles